# Update current position in android Gps LocationListener

Tags: android, gps, position, locationmanager

I'm watching other posts, but I can't do mine. I want to update my position and start an alarm noise when I am "x" meters of my targetLocation.

I have used this code:

```
private TextView m1TextMessage, m2TextMessage, m3TextMessage;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private Location targetLocation;
double longitude, latitude;
private float distancia;
ProgressDialog pd;
LocationListener listener;
```

Here is my LocationListener:

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        float dist=0;
        float error=0;

        //Escribir posición actual en m1TextMessage
        latitude =location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();

        //calcular distancia al destino y error estimado
        //Escribir distancia al destino y error en m3TextMessage

        Location loc2= new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

         if (loc2 != null)  
            {
               dist=location.distanceTo(targetLocation);
               error = location.getAccuracy();
               if(dist < distancia){
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Distancia menor a 10 metros, "+dist+" metros.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                   Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                   Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
                   r.play();
                  }
            }else
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "location actual es null!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


           m1TextMessage.setText("Posición actual: "+longitude+", "+latitude+"\n");
            m2TextMessage.setText("Posición objetivo: "+targetLocation.getLatitude()+", "+targetLocation.getLongitude()+"\n");
            m3TextMessage.setText("Distancia al objetivo: "+dist+"\nError estimado: "+error);
        //Lanzar un Toast si la distancia al destino es inferior a 10 metros

    }

};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    m1TextMessage=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.actualPos);
    m2TextMessage=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.destino);
    m3TextMessage=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.distanciaa);
    Button localiza = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    localiza.setOnClickListener(this);


}

public class GPSLocation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{  
    boolean running =true;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute()
            {  
                super.onPreExecute(); 
                pd = new ProgressDialog(PracticaGPS.this);
                pd.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){
                      public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                          pd.cancel();  
                      }
                });
                longitude=0;
                latitude =0;
                getLonLat();
                pd.setCancelable(true);
                pd.setMessage("Getting GPS Location...");
                pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

                pd.show();

            } 

            @Override 
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);


                // Things to be done while execution of long running operation is in progress. For example updating ProgessDialog
             }

            @Override 
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
            {  


                    pd.dismiss(); 
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {  
                boolean isDataSubmitted = false;

                while(!isDataSubmitted)
                {  
                    if(longitude !=0 && latitude!=0)
                    { 

                        isDataSubmitted = true;
                        Log.d("LONGITUD", ""+longitude);
                        Log.d("LATITUDE", ""+latitude);

                    }  
                } 

                return null;    
            } 
 } 


public void getLonLat(){
    listener = new MyLocationListener();

    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        (locationManager).requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10,listener);
         new GPSLocation().execute();
    }else if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, listener);
        Log.d("Long", ""+longitude);
    } else 
        enableLocationSettings();

}

@Override
public void onStart(){

    //Crear servicio de localización LocationManager       
    //Determinar si el GPS está encendido
    //Caso esté apagado, permitir al usuario activarlo mediante método enableLocationSettings()

    //Solicitar actualizaciones de posición al proveedor de GPS (opcionalmente también al proveedor de red)
    //Nota: el LocationListener ya ha sido creado: listener


    super.onStart();
}


private void enableLocationSettings() { //enable Location services is necessary
    Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(settingsIntent);
}


@Override
public void onStop(){
     locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
     super.onStop();
}

public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText lat, lon, distan;
        lat = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.latitud);
        lon = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.longitud);
        targetLocation = new Location("Target Position");
        targetLocation.setLatitude(Double.valueOf(lat.getText().toString())); //punto pre-definido,
        targetLocation.setLongitude(Double.valueOf(lon.getText().toString())); //no cambiar el valor
        targetLocation.setAltitude(0);
        distan = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.distancia);
        distancia = Float.valueOf(distan.getText().toString());
        new GPSLocation().execute();

}
```

}

Here is my xml code :

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Longitud: " />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/longitud"
        android:layout_width="101dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texto2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Latitud: " />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/latitud"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Distancia mínima alarma" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/distancia"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enviar Localizacion" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actualPos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/destino"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

         />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/distanciaa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

         />
```

I guess is pretty Simple but I can manage it. Thank you.

Comment: you are getting your current position correct right ?

Answer (score 0):

Read this.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html

Use this function

```
public static void distanceBetween (double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double endLatitude, double endLongitude, float[] results)
```

Get the results from the function and minus it with the target location in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

if you will call this method correctly whenever you want to get the distance from your current location to target location .. this will provide the distance.. as per the google services. simpley it will return values... it will work nicely. hope it will help you.

```
package com.google.map;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
public class Distance   {

public String getDistance(String Source,String Destination) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String duration_final_value = "";
    try {

        Source = Source.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
        Destination = Destination.replaceAll(" ", "%20");

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="
                        + Source + "&destination=" + Destination
                        + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving");//&mode=walking,driving
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        response = client.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
        int b;
        while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
            stringBuilder.append((char) b);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString()); // first we need to get the full json object which google returns    
        JSONArray routes_Array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes"); // in that first we need to go into the routes array
        JSONObject routes_object = (JSONObject) routes_Array.get(0); // in that we need first item 
        JSONArray legs_Array = routes_object.getJSONArray("legs");  // then go into the legs array
        JSONObject legs_object = (JSONObject) legs_Array.get(0);  // in that we need first item.
        JSONObject duration_object = legs_object.getJSONObject("distance"); // go into the distance object      
        // pull out the "duration" object
        duration_final_value = duration_object.getString("text"); // this should be the duration text value (20 hours 40 mins)



    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return duration_final_value;
}
}
```